# Add custom web service to Program AB using sraix tag?

Tags: chatbot, aiml

I am using Program AB to make some tests creating a chatbot. What I need is to be able to `feed` my bot with live information from my own web service.

It is my understanding that that is what the new tag in `AIML 2.0` `sraix` is for. But I can't find any documentation on how to use it and how to hook it to my own web service.

I tried searching for how the bot SUPER uses the tag but what I can find doesn't seem to point to any web service.

Can anyone share any example on how to use `sraix` with a custom web service?

Any tip in the right direction will be appreciated,
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A rather simple is write a backend program and keep webservice address in aiml. If a request matches the template, it will return a webservice path and you browse it to retrieve data in code,e.g. java Jersey framework is used for restful webservices, so a specific webservice url will be returned upon matching the pattern, which will be further processed in your backend application and response sent back to view.Simplest approach is using php or jsp.